# android view animation cycleinterpolator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

I have a view. I want to change its alpha from 1 to 0 and then repeat for a number of time.
I believe I have to use animation for that. But I don't know how to use the CycleInterpolator in android. Might anyone show me a code sample? I have gotten as far as

```
CycleInterpolator ci = new CycleInterpolator(5f);
ViewPropertyAnimator anim = myView.animate();
anim.alpha(0);
anim.setDuration(10000);
anim.setInterpolator(ci);
```

*EDIT*

the code above works, but it is very brisk. All I see is blinking. I want the view to fade out and then back in very slowly about once every second or two or three. I really need the transition to be smooth and slow and visible to the human eye.

Comment: @btse see my edit notes.

Comment: Even with the 10 second duration it's too fast?

Comment: It does not fade in or out. It just blinks and then waits: solid. but the blink lasts a split second. There is no transition that I can detect.

Comment: @btse the docs say `Maps a value representing the elapsed fraction of an animation to a value that represents the interpolated fraction. This interpolated value is then multiplied by the change in value of an animation to derive the animated value at the current elapsed animation time.` so the value is not number of revolutions? do you understand the docs?

Comment: Yeah that means its more like a sinusoid. Have you tried using a `LinearInterpolator` instead to see what happens and also perhaps placing the `setDuration()` and `setInterpolator()` calls first (although this shouldn't technically make any difference).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38581/discussion-between-btse-and-cote-mounyo)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`myview.animate().alpha(0).setInterpolator(new CycleInterpolator(<Number of cycles>))`

You can also find all of the different methods of a `ViewPropertyAnimator`  [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html).